# Jupyter Notebook Python3 Support

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ubuntu-18.04

I want to be able to use Python3 on jupyter notebook and my operating system is Linux Ubuntu 18.04.

Issue is that, although I followed the certain steps about creating virtual environment, installing the jupyter via pip, etc., after I open Jupyter on Chrome browser, I am unable to create a Python3 notebook because there is only Python2 option from the dropdown menu.

Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with:

```
sudo pip3 install jupyter
```